# Ubuntu 17.04 + Windows 10 Dualboot Corrupts My Ubuntu Partition

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, data-corruption

I installed Ubuntu 17.04 (Budgie) just fine a couple days ago as a second partition on my hard drive (the other being Windows 10), and I wasn't having any problems until I decided to boot to Windows again. When I did, it told me there were errors with the drive, and it needed to be repaired (another problem that happened was the computer's time was incorrect, despite being set to automatically retrieve it, but I'm not sure if that means anything). I accepted the notification's prompt, and after working for a while, it told me I needed to reboot. When I logged back into Windows, it said the problem was fixed. The next day when I wanted to switch back to Ubuntu, nothing worked. I don't remember what exactly it told me, but if I recall correctly it appeared as though the entire partition was cleared of it's memory.

I was very upset by this, and couldn't think of any explanation other than Windows was being a jerk, and it decided I wasn't allowed to run multiple partitions on the same hard drive where Windows was already installed. I wasn't done though, and I tried installing a different Linux distro (Korora), but this time I couldn't even get the install process to run, a GUI didn't even load. I altered the boot settings, taking off secure boot and fast boot, but nothing worked.

I decided to go back to Ubuntu 17.04 (the regular version this time, no flavor) because I really want to start using Linux. Once again the install went by fine, and this time when I booted Windows again I made sure not to accept the prompt, which I received again. Unfortunately, despite ignoring the prompt, Ubuntu was compromised once again, but this time I made sure to take a picture of what I get when I try to run Ubuntu from the GRUB menu.

[I have no idea what this means](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa5FE.jpg)

Something to note though, I believe my files are still there this time (although I'm not sure if they were really gone the first time this happened). I tried reinstalling Ubuntu without compromising my files, but it just gets stuck when it tries preserving the programs I've installed, making no progress.

The only thing I can think of that Windows might think is wrong with the hard drive is the fact that I encrypted my home folder both times I installed Ubuntu, but I don't even know if that makes sense. The thing is, I don't feel there's actually been anything wrong with my hard drive when Windows says there is.

Give it to me straight doc... What's going on here?

EDIT: At this point I don't care if I lose my files on Ubuntu as long as Ubuntu doesn't keep breaking every time

To be clear the problem is that after every time I boot to Windows, I can no longer boot to Ubuntu. I've reinstalled Ubuntu several times without any problems, and it continues to work, even if I reboot to Ubuntu, but as soon as I boot back to Windows, I can no longer boot to Ubuntu.

Comment: What brand/model system? Is system set for AHCI, not RAID nor IDE? What video card/chip and are you installing a proprietary driver and/or do you need nomodeset or other boot parameters? Is Windows fast start up off. UEFI or BIOS install? http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions and: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: Have you installed any drivers on Windows that allows you to access Ubuntu EXT4 partitions? Please edit your question to include a current-window-only screenshot of `gparted` and I'll take a look at how bad the damage might be. Also... this is important... check for a BIOS update for your computer at the manufacturer's web site. Start comments directed to me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema I'm a little confused. Do you want me to re-install Ubuntu, because as far as I know gparted is Linux only software, and if I wasn't clear, I can't run Ubuntu at the moment. I'll be sure to check for a BIOS update though.

Comment: No, I wasn't asking you to reinstall Ubuntu, yet. With all of the trouble that you were having, I was trying to determine... 1)if you had installed any drivers in Windows that allow you to read Ubuntu partitions, and 2)I wanted to look at your disk structure to see what condition it's in after having 3 operating systems there. Yes, `gparted` is Linux software, but you can get to it from the Ubuntu Live DVD/USB if you can't boot into Ubuntu normally. Yes, check the BIOS... good.